to_timestamp stipping zeros in milliseconds
I am trying to convert the string column in (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS) to timestamp (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS). I am using the to_timestamp() function which works fine up to millisecond but if the data is like '2023-05-03 00:00:00.000' or '2023-05-03 04:06:25.000' it is stripping those end 000 and the output is 2023-05-03 00:00:00. I want 000 to be there as well. It is important because I have to validate the data and  that I am comparing to have 2023-05-03 00:00:00.000. The data type is timestamp so I cannot use date_format().
spark.sql("select '2023-05-03T00:00:00.000' as string_date, date_format('2023-05-03T00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as date_formatted,to_timestamp(date_format('2023-05-03T00:00:00','yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS') as t" ).show(truncate=False)

+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|string_date            |date_formatted         |t                  |
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+
|2023-05-03T00:00:00.000|2023-05-03 00:00:00.000|2023-05-03 00:00:00|
+-----------------------+-----------------------+-------------------+

I want 2023-05-03 00:00:00.000 as timestamp output

It's just the way it's displayed. Dataframe's show() function probably just uses datetime.__str__() to render that object as string. And that function just skips the microseconds if it's zero while converting it to a string.
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str(datetime(2023, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0))
'2023-05-03 00:00:00'
>>> str(datetime(2023, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1))
'2023-05-03 00:00:00.000001'
>>>

It isn't really stripped/lost, you can use date_format to override how show() displays your value.
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = spark.sql("""select
...     to_timestamp(date_format('2023-05-03T00:00:00.000000', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') as t1,
...     to_timestamp(date_format('2023-05-03T00:00:00.000001', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS') as t2
...     """)
>>>
>>> df = df.withColumn('t1_str', F.date_format(F.col('t1'), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS'))
>>>
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|t1                 |t2                        |t1_str                    |
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|2023-05-03 00:00:00|2023-05-03 00:00:00.000001|2023-05-03 00:00:00.000000|
+-------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+

>>>
>>> row = df.collect()[0].asDict()
>>> row
{'t1': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 3, 0, 0), 't2': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1), 't1_str': '2023-05-03 00:00:00.000000'}
>>> row['t1'].microsecond
0
>>> row['t1_str']
'2023-05-03 00:00:00.000000'
>>> row['t2'].microsecond
1
>>>


date_format will convert it to string format, right? I want it to be a timestamp. Is it only stripping zeros when doing show? I

yes, "it is only stripping zeros when doing show". See t2 in my answer.
